# Apache2 not rewriting as expected

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have a VPS on Digital ocean, hosting two websites, each with multiple domains.

Website 1: https://jeremiahrose.com/

Alternative domains:
`jeremiahro.se`,
`jeremiahrose.band`,
`www.jeremiahrose.com`,
`www.jeremiahro.se`,
`www.jeremiahrose.band`

Website 2: https://thewilliewagtails.band/

Alternative domains:
`thewilliewagtails.com`,
`thewilliewagtails.com.au`,
`www.thewilliewagtails.band`,
`www.thewilliewagtails.com`,
`www.thewilliewagtails.com.au`,

I'm trying to set it up so that a request to any of the alternative domains (http or https) redirects to the secure canonical domain for that website. e.g `www.thewilliewagtails.com` redirects to `https://thewilliewagtails.band`.

It's currently only half working - [www.thewilliewagtails.com](http://www.thewilliewagtails.com/) and [thewilliewagtails.com](http://thewilliewagtails.com) are returning a default page, and [thewilliewagtails.band/](http://thewilliewagtails.band/) is not redirecting.

I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is, I'm clearly out of my depth here.

```
jez@jeremiahrose:/etc/apache2$ ls sites-enabled/
000-default.conf  jeremiahrose.com.conf  thewilliewagtails.band.conf
```

### 000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

### jeremiahrose.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/jeremiahrose.com

        <Directory /var/www/jeremiahrose.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

    ServerName jeremiahrose.com
        ServerAlias jeremiahro.se
        ServerAlias jeremiahrose.band
        ServerAlias www.jeremiahrose.com
        ServerAlias www.jeremiahro.se
        ServerAlias www.jeremiahrose.band


    RewriteEngine on
    #Added automatically by let's encrypt:
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.jeremiahrose.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jeremiahrose.band [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.jeremiahro.se [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jeremiahro.se [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jeremiahrose.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.jeremiahrose.band
    RewriteRule ^ https://jeremiahrose.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/jeremiahrose.com

        <Directory /var/www/jeremiahrose.com/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

    ServerName jeremiahrose.com
    ServerAlias jeremiahro.se
    ServerAlias jeremiahrose.band
    ServerAlias www.jeremiahrose.com
    ServerAlias www.jeremiahro.se
    ServerAlias www.jeremiahrose.band

    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.jeremiahrose.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jeremiahrose.band [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.jeremiahro.se [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =jeremiahro.se [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.jeremiahrose.band
        RewriteRule ^ https://jeremiahrose.com%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jeremiahro.se/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jeremiahro.se/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

### thewilliewagtails.band.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/thewilliewagtails.band

        <Directory /var/www/thewilliewagtails.band/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

    ServerName thewilliewagtails.band
        ServerAlias thewilliewagtails.com.au
        ServerAlias thewilliewagtails.com
        ServerAlias wwww.thewilliewagtails.com
        ServerAlias www.thewilliewagtails.com.au
        ServerAlias www.thewilliewagtails.band


    RewriteEngine on
    #Added automatically by let's encrypt:
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.band [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com.au [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com.au
    RewriteRule ^ https://thewilliewagtails.band%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>


<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/thewilliewagtails.band

        <Directory /var/www/thewilliewagtails.band/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
        </IfModule>

    ServerName thewilliewagtails.band
    ServerAlias thewilliewagtails.com
    ServerAlias thewilliewagtails.com.au
    ServerAlias www.thewilliewagtails.com
    ServerAlias www.thewilliewagtails.com.au
    ServerAlias www.thewilliewagtails.band

    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com.au [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com.au [OR]
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.band
        RewriteRule ^ https://thewilliewagtails.band%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jeremiahro.se/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jeremiahro.se/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Try to remove all the "RewriteCond" and let the RewriteRule work without it.

Comment: @Orphans If you simply removed "all" the `RewriteCond` directives in the code as it stands then you will get a redirect loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's currently only half working - `www.thewilliewagtails.com` and `thewilliewagtails.com` are returning a default page, and `thewilliewagtails.band/` is not redirecting.

I can't just see why `thewilliewagtails.com` wouldn't be working. However, you have a typo in your `<VirtualHost *:80>` container, that matches `wwww`, not `www` in the `ServerAlias` - so this will simply never match:

```
ServerAlias wwww.thewilliewagtails.com
```

And `thewilliewagtails.band` is omitted from your HTTP to HTTPS (`<VirtualHost *:80>`) redirect (missing `RewriteCond` directive) - so, yes, that will not be redirected in the current config. Instead of checking every possible hostname it should not be, you only need to check that it is *not* the canonical hostname (see below).

I completely agree with @roaima's answer. However, you are part way there with your current config and your directives can be greatly simplified.

Since your canonical port is 443, you only need an unconditional mod_alias `Redirect` in the `<VirtualHost *:80>` containers (mod_rewrite is not required) to effectively create the HTTP to HTTPS redirect. So, for example, the following mod_rewrite block:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> #Added automatically by let's encrypt:
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.band [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com.au [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com.au
> RewriteRule ^ https://thewilliewagtails.band%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

Can be immediately replaced with a simple/unconditional mod_alias `Redirect` instead:

```
Redirect 301 / https://thewilliewagtails.band/
```

And the corresponding mod_rewrite canonical redirect in the `<VirtualHost *:443>` can be greatly simplified. Instead of checking against every hostname that it could be, you only need to check that it is not the canonical hostname. For example, the following:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.com.au [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =thewilliewagtails.com.au [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.thewilliewagtails.band
> RewriteRule ^ https://thewilliewagtails.band%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
> ```

Can be immediately replaced with the simpler:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^thewilliewagtails\.band$
RewriteRule ^ https://thewilliewagtails.band%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
```

There is now a lot less to remember/get wrong.

However, I'd probably still go with creating a separate vHost container for the non-canonical port 443 hostnames as @roaima suggests. You can then use an unconditional mod_alias `Redirect` and get rid of mod_rewrite altogether.

Comment: Thanks MrWhite! Fixing the wwww typo and replacing the rewrites as you suggested fixed everything. It also turns out Chrome automatically changes "thewilliewagtails.com" into "www.thewilliewagtails.com" without asking, so that problem was on my end.
I'm considering adding an extra vHost for each website as you and @roaima suggest - but I'm not sure of the rational. Is mod_rewrite considered bad form?

Comment: "Chrome automatically changes `thewilliewagtails.com` into `www.thewilliewagtails.com` without asking" - Chrome would only do that if there was a cached 301 redirect, or inadvertently selecting the _auto-complete_ suggestion in Chrome's omni-box.

Comment: "Is mod_rewrite considered bad form?" - It's primarily a performance thing. mod_rewrite is more "expensive" than a simple mod_alias `Redirect`. But also having a separate vHost just for the non-canonical domains also improves performance for when the site is being accessed via the canonical domain. If the redirect code was in the one vHost (which would need to be mod_rewrite in this instance - as you have above) then this code is executed on every request, even when the canonical domain is accessed. It doesn't need to be if you have a separate vHost.

Comment: By "performance", we aren't necessarily talking about huge performance gains; more about keeping things efficient and simple.

Comment: RE Chrome, see this question https://superuser.com/questions/965229/why-does-google-chrome-automatically-add-www-prefix-for-some-websites-but-it-do#965230

Answer (score 1):

Easier solution without getting into complicated rewrite rulesets.

For each website and its aliases:

1. Create a canonical vHost configuration for the website. Accept only the single canonical name.
2. Create a non-canonical vHost containing all the alternate names, and use a simple `Redirect` to send users to the corresponding canonical vHost.

Comment: Folks, if you're going to downvote please at least let me know what you don't like about this answer.